# Java wait for the operation to finish to continue

Tags: java, spring-boot, rollback

My method makes an update on the database, and then after it tries to send an email, the latter could go into exception, and when it goes into exception, the database is not updated. How can I solve? Thanks in advance

```
userRepository.save(user);

if (user.isAccepted()) {
    try {
        mailSender.sendEmail(user);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new MailToNotFoundException(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: put your save call into the if after the try

Comment: If you want to save the `user` regardless of any exceptions then you can put  `userRepository.save(user);` in the `finally`  block of the used `try-catch`

Comment: I can't do this because my if statement depends on the update

Comment: "when it goes into exception, the database is not updated". Are you sure that the exception raised is a MailToNotFoundException ?

Comment: so apparently if exception is thrown from your method, db is not updated but you want to update your db even after exception is thrown? is that the case?

Comment: @bloub yes, in the log i can see MailNotFoundException

Comment: @AshishPatil yes, i wanna my db got updated independently if throw exception or not

Comment: I think there might be something wrong in you save method. Like a commit() to the database missing (and maybe done further in your code). But it's wild guess.

Comment: Guys i solved with "@Transactional(noRollbackFor = MailToNotFoundException.class)"

Comment: @sweet, for handling any general purpose exception, consider using `flush()` inside exception before calling `throw new Exception()..`